# Thread syncronization with boost::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

I'm currently using boost 1.55.0, and I cant understand why this code doesn't work.

The following code is a simplification that has the same problem as my program. Small runs finish, but when they are bigger the threads keep waiting forever.

```
boost::mutex m1;
boost::mutex critical_sim;

int total= 50000;

class krig{

public:

    float dokrig(int in,float *sim, bool *aux, boost::condition_variable *hEvent){

        float simnew=0;

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(m1);

        if (in > 0)
        {
            while(!aux[in-1]){
                hEvent[in-1].wait(lk);  
            }
            simnew=1+sim[in-1];

        }

        return simnew;
    };

};

void Simulnode( int itrd,float *sim, bool *aux, boost::condition_variable *hEvent){
    int j;
    float simnew;

    krig kriga;

    for(j=itrd; j<total; j=j+2){

        if (fmod(1000.*j,total) == 0.0){
            printf (" .progress. %f%%\n",100.*(float)j/(float)total);
        }

        simnew= kriga.dokrig(j,sim, aux, hEvent);

        critical_sim.lock();
        sim[j]=simnew;
        critical_sim.unlock();

        aux[j]=true;
        hEvent[j].notify_one();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    float *sim = new float[total];

    bool *aux = new bool[total];

    for(i=0; i<total; ++i)
        aux[i]=false;

//boost::mutex m1;

    boost::condition_variable *hEvent = new boost::condition_variable[total];

    boost::thread_group tgroup;
    for(i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        tgroup.add_thread(new boost::thread(Simulnode, i,sim, aux, hEvent));

    }
    tgroup.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Curiously, I noticed that if I place the code that is inside dokrig() inline in simulnode() then it seems to work. Can it be some problem with the scope of the lock?

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens in this part:

```
aux[j]=true;
hEvent[j].notify_one();
```

The first line represents a change of the condition that is being monitored by the `hEvent` condition variable. The second line proclaims this change to the consumer part, that is waiting for that condition to become true.

The problem is that these two steps happen without synchronization with the consumer, which can lead to the following race:

- The consumer checks the condition, which is currently false. This happens in a critical section protected by the mutex `m1`.
- A thread switch occurs. The producer changes the condition to true and notifies any waiting consumers.
- Threads switch back. The consumer resumes and calls wait. However, he already missed the notify that occurred in the last step, so he will wait forever.

It is important to understand that the purpose of the mutex that is passed to the `wait` call of the condition variable is not to protect the condition variable itself, but the *condition that it monitors* (which in this case is the change to `aux`).

To avoid the data race, writing to `aux` and the subsequent notify have to be protected by the same mutex:

```
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(m1);
    aux[j]=true;
    hEvent[j].notify_one();
}
```